# How to reduce the script lines for same table join condition in multiple times in oracle?

Tags: oracle, join

There are two tables table1 and table2.

```
Table1 is as below:
col1 | col2 | Col3
 A     10     X
 B     11     X
 C     10     X
 A     20     X
```

Table2 is as below:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
 A      10     1     UDHAY
 B      11     2     VIJAY
 C      10     1     SURESH
 A      20     2     ARUL
 A      10     3     UDHAY
 B      11     4     VIJAY
 C      10     4     SURESH
 A      20     5     ARUL
```

I want to display the column col4 in table2 with  3 join conditions as below.

```
    table1.COl1 = table2.COl1
and table1.COl2 = table2.COl2
and table2.COl3 = '1'
```

Sample query :

```
   select   
   table2.col4 
    from table1 
    left outer join table2 
    on(
        table1.COl1 = table2.COl1
        and table1.COl2 = table2.COl2
        and table2.COl3 = '1');
```

Question: IF I want to display `table2.col4` for condition table2.col3 1,2,3,4,5 with matching other condition from table1, how to make the script?

Actually I know we can add same table 5 times with different alias names and can print. But I don't want to repeat the same condition 5 times. Only the `where` conditions should be common for all 5 values.

---

Added on 30-OCT-2013:

Thanks for your response. NO not like you mentioned by using IN. Right now I am using below script concept :

```
  select  A.col1,A.co2,B1.col4 ,B2.col4,B3.col4.B4.col4
  from table1 A
  left outer join table2 B1
  on(
    A.COl1 = B1.COl1
    and A.COl2 = B1.COl2
    and B1.COl3 = '1')
left outer join table2 B2
     on(
    A.COl1 = B2.COl1
    and A.COl2 = B2.COl2
    and B2.COl3 = '2')
left outer join table2 B3
     on(
    A.COl1 = B3.COl1
    and A.COl2 = B3.COl2
    and B3.COl3 = '3')
left outer join table2 B4
     on(
    A.COl1 = B4.COl1
    and A.COl2 = B4.COl2
    and B4.COl3 = '4');
```

So my output will be:

```
 A | 10 | UDHAY | |UDHAY| |
 B | 11 | | VIJAY| | VIJAY |
 C | 10 | SURESH | | | SURESH |
 A | 20 | | ARUL | | |
```

But like above script I have to make it for 25 combination (1 to 25). So if I make the script like above the script lines will be more than 200 lines. To avoid that will you please help to suggest some other method to reduce the script lines and  get the same output?

Comment: `and table2.COl3 = '1' in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm getting you correctly, do you mean something like this?

```
and table2.COl3 IN ('1','2','3','4','5')
```

Comment: HI DElo,                                                      Thanks for ur response: please see my comments in question after    Added on 30-OCT-2013:

Answer (score 0):

First solution (trivial):
Make a view with the whole set of Joins and query for it instead on your script, it's a bit dodgy but gets your script to be shorter. If your data set ends up growing off the scales you could switch to a materialized view instead and simplify what could end up being a costly plan.

Second solution (not so trivial):
If your tables do have a name convention you could write a PL block and loop through it, going around and arraying the tables that you want to join so that you can concat the joins on runtime in a string and run it as dynamic SQL.